# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, instance-variables

I want to find instance variable in class but I am getting error 
Please can anyone help me where I am going to wrong 
Thanks in advance

```py
class PythonSwitch:

    def switch(self, typeOfInfo,nameofclass):
        default = "invalid input"
        return getattr(self, 'info_' + str(typeOfInfo), lambda: default)(nameofclass)

    def info_1(self,nameofclass):
        print("Class name : ",__class__.__name__)
        print("---------- Method of class ----------")
        print(dir(nameofclass))
        print("---------- Instance variable in class ----------")
        print(nameofclass.__dict__)

    def info_2(self,nameofclass):
        print("---------- Method of class ----------")
        print(dir(nameofclass))

    def info_3(self,nameofclass):
        print("---------- Instance variable in class ----------")
        print(nameofclass.__dict__)


s = PythonSwitch()

print(s.switch(1,"PythonSwitch"))
print(s.switch(0,"PythonSwitch"))
```

Comment: If your problem was resolved please mark the answer as correct so your question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of class shouldn't be a string your code uses the real class object so change to this:

```
s = PythonSwitch()

print(s.switch(1,PythonSwitch))
print(s.switch(0,PythonSwitch))
```

Doing it the way you did just passes a string object which as stated by the your output does not poses a `__dict__` attribute.

**EDIT**
Also there is one more error in your code:

`return getattr(self, 'info_' + str(typeOfInfo), lambda: default)(nameofclass)`

This line is incorret because your lambda expression doesn't expects any value and it should because every method gets at least one parameter that is `self`. So you need to change it to:

`return getattr(self, 'info_' + str(typeOfInfo), lambda self: default (nameofclass)`